# Cómo pasar un input del HTML a una variable en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

No puedo pasar un input a una variable

El código que estoy intentando es el siguiente:

```
<h2>product code</h2>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="prod">
        <h2>shelf code</h2>
        <input type="text" name="shelf">
        <input type="submit" name="sub" class="sub" value="submit" onclick="sub()">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //variables
    var product = null;
    var shelf = null;
    var status = null;

        //submit
        function sub(){
            product = document.getElementById("prod");
            shelf = document.getElementById("shelf");
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas llamando los elementos por id, sin embargo no estas definiendo ningun id para tus inputs por eso no obtienes ningun valor.

Si quires obtener los elementos por nombre podrias hacer algo así

```js
    var product = null;
    var shelf = null;
    var status = null;

function sub(){
  product = document.getElementsByName("prod")[0].value;
  shelf = document.getElementsByName("shelf")[0].value;
  alert(product+" "+shelf);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS NAME</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>product code</h2>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="prod">
        <h2>shelf code</h2>
        <input type="text" name="shelf">
    </form>
    <button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>
</body>
</html>
```

O si quieres mantener tu codigo agregale los id a cada Input, algo así:

```js
    var product = null;
    var shelf = null;
    var status = null;

        //submit
        function sub(){
            product = document.getElementById("prod").value;
            shelf = document.getElementById("shelf").value;
         alert(product+" "+shelf);
        };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS NAME</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>product code</h2>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="prod" id="prod">
        <h2>shelf code</h2>
        <input type="text" name="shelf" id="shelf">
    </form>
    <button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @acoronas Si esta respuesta solucionó a tu problema, por favor considerá **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda de la respuesta

Comment: Buenos días,
Y si el javascript está en un archivo independiente, ¿cómo se le pasan los valores?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">

<title> Formulario de trabajadores </title>

<H1 align="center"> Gustos musicales </h1>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#66fff" text="#0000ff">

<form method="get" action="">

<div>

<label for="nombre"> Nombre: </label> </br>

<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

</div>

<div>

<label for="edad"> Edad: </label> </br>

<input type="int" name="edad" id="edad">

</div>

<div>

<label for="genero"> Genero musical preferido: </label> </br>

<input type="text" name="genero" id="genero">

</div>

<div>

<label for="horas"> Cuantas horas dedicas a escuchar este genero en especifico? (al dia): </label> </br>

<input type="int" name="horas" id="horas">

</div>

<div>

<label for="porque"> Describe por que te gusta este genero musical:</label> </br>

<textarea name="porque" id="porque">

</textarea>

</div>

<div>

<button onclick ="sub()"> Enviar </button>

</div>

</body>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var name = null;

var age = null;

var genre = null;

var hrs = null;

var why = null;

function sub(){

name = document.getElementById("nombre")[0].value;

age = document.getElementById("edad")[0].value;

genre = document.getElementById("genero")[0].value;

hrs = document.getElementById("hrs")[0].value;

why = document.getElementById("why")[0].value;

alert(name+" "+age);

};

<script>

</html>
```

Comment: deberias haber agregado una breve explicacion a tu respuesta..!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes buscar los datos por nombre de la forma y sus hijos. Aqui un ejemplo sencillo que se explica solo.

```js
    function EnviarForma() {

     //obtencion de datos de html
      var nombre = document.forms["miForma"]["nombrePersona"].value;
      var telefono= document.forms["miForma"]["telefonoPersona"].value;
      //validacion
      var validacion=true;
      if (nombre == "")  {
         console.log('error,nombre vacio');
        validacion=false;
      }
      if(telefono=="")
      {
      console.log('error: telefono no puede ir vacio');
      validacion= false;
      }
      if(!validacion)
      {
      return false;
      }
      //enviar los datos
    }
```

```html
    <form name="miForma" action="" onsubmit="return EnviarForma()" method="post">
      Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombrePersona">
      <br/>
      Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefonoPersona">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```